# Is there a way to redirect the output of ":ilist pattern" to a Vim quickfix window?

Tags: vim

I use quickfix windows all the time to traverse cscope results all the time.

So I was wondering if there something similar for "Include file searches" (:help ilist)

Comment: There's no buit-in way. Maybe parsing the output of `:ilist` and feeding it to `:cexpr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [/r/vim](http://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/1rzvsm/a/cdssovl):

```
function! WordOccurance()
    redir => output
        silent! exec join(['ilist', expand('<cword>')], ' ')
    redir END
    let lines = split(output, '\n')
    if lines[0] =~ '^Error detected'
        echomsg "Could not find the word in file"
        return
    endif
    let [filename, line_info] = [lines[0], lines[1:-1]]
    let qf_entries = map(line_info, "{
            \ 'filename': filename,
            \ 'lnum': split(v:val)[1],
            \ 'text': getline(split(v:val)[1])
            \ }"
        \ )
    call setqflist(qf_entries)
    cwindow
endfunction
noremap <silent> ]I :call WordOccurance()<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

First off all, `:ilist` searches the *current buffer*, not "include file searches".

My [GrepHere plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4191) provides a `:GrepHere` command that works like `:ilist`, but puts the matches into the *quickfix window*.